# Pop up sign up tracking using google tag manager google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to implement the described tracking on 2 of my websites. On one of the website there is a sign-up button which on click will pop up a window and ask for user credentials. The pop-up that comes is from another website which validates the credential.

After the credentials are successfully validated, the user is returned to the page where he/she clicked the sign up button. Can any one suggest how to track this using Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Can you please post the work that you have already done, and what code you have attempted for this tracking?

Comment: I have not yet started as I am not able figure out how to implement the request. This is the first time I am working on a request which involves 2 website to track the data .

Comment: is that popup an iframe? if it is, then you need an API that will confirm that user did log in and then you refresh your page and track the event

Comment: Thanks Ante for the reply. It is not iframe. Just wanted to if cross domain tracking will work here? Can you advice on the same.

Comment: One option is to put your GTM container code on the iframed site.